# Regex in C# How to replace only capture groups and not non-capture groups

Tags: c#, regex, capture-group

I am writing a regular expression in Visual Studios 2013 Express using C#. I am trying to put single quotes around every single string that includes words and !@#$%^&*()_- except for:

- and
- or
- not
- empty()
- notempty()
- currentdate()
- any string that already has single quotes around it.

Here is my regex and a sample of what it does:
https://regex101.com/r/nI1qP0/1

I want put single quotes only around the capture groups and leave the non-capture groups untouched. I know this can be done with lookarounds, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to ignore the strings with words and!@#$%^&*()_- in them, I just included them in my search, placed an extra single quote on either end, and then remove all instances of two single quotes like so:

```
 // Find any string of words and !@#$%^&*()_- in and out of quotes.
 Regex getwords = new Regex(@"(^(?!and\b)(?!or\b)(?!not\b)(?!empty\b)(?!notempty\b)(?!currentdate\b)([\w!@#$%^&*())_-]+)|((?!and\b)(?!or\b)(?!not\b)(?!empty\b)(?!notempty\b)(?!currentdate\b)(?<=\W)([\w!@#$%^&*()_-]+)|('[\w\s!@#$%^&*()_-]+')))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 // Find all cases of two single quotes
 Regex getQuotes = new Regex(@"('')");

 // Get string from user
 Console.WriteLine("Type in a string");
 string search = Console.ReadLine();

 // Execute Expressions.
 search = getwords.Replace(search, "'$1'");
 search = getQuotes.Replace(search, "'");
```

Comment: It is great you found a solution that suits you. Please consider upvoting the answers that were helpful to you.

Comment: I wasn't able to till just now because I'm new at stack overflow, but now that my reputation is above 15 I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:'[^']*'|(?:\b(?:(?:not)?empty|currentdate)\(\)|and|or|not))|([!@#$%^&*_.\w-]‌​+)
```

Here ignored matches are not captured and **words to be quoted can be retrieved using `Match.Groups[1]`**. You can then add quotes around `Match.Groups[1]` and get the whole input replaced as you want.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI1qP0/3)

Comment: That is close, but it doesn't capture any of the characters !@#$%^&*()-_ . Even when i add them in the (\w+) part as ([!@#$%^&*()_-w/]+) it doesn't work if they are on the end of the words.

Comment: `!@#$%^&*()` are not considered word characters and you wrote **every single word**. You can use this regex: `(?:'[^']*'|(?:\b(?:(?:not)?empty|currentdate)\(\)|and|or|not))|([!@#$%^&*_.\w-]+)`. See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/nI1qP0/3

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. Sorry about that. This one works great.

Comment: The regex works, but when I try replacing everything in my c# code, it just replaces everything with 'capture'. I'm still trying to figure out how to make it work with match.Groups[1].

Comment: Alright, I edited my question with the regex expression you suggested. I think that I'm not really understanding how match.Group works. I already read the MSDN description of it.

Comment: I found a completely different solution that I am going to use instead. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a match evaluator, or a callback method. The point is that you can examine the match and captured groups inside this method, and decide what action to take depending on your pattern.

So, add this callback method (may be non-static if the calling method is non-static):

```
public static string repl(Match m)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[1].Value) ?
        m.Value.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, string.Format("'{0}'", m.Groups[1].Value)) :
        m.Value;
}
```

Then, use an [overload of `Regex.Replace` with the match evaluator (=callback method)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var s = "'This is not captured' but this is and not or empty() notempty() currentdate() capture";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?:'[^']*'|(?:\b(?:(?:not)?empty|currentdate)\(\)|and|or|not))|([!@#$%^&*_.\w-]+)");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Replace(s, repl));
```

Note you can shorten the code with a lambda expression:

```
Console.WriteLine(rx.Replace(s, m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[1].Value) ?
    m.Value.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, string.Format("'{0}'", m.Groups[1].Value)) :
    m.Value));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/LMNdFs)

Comment: It's theoretically possible this would fail, since you're doing a text-match of your group.  So like, if your regex matches and it has multiple instances of the text that appears in your group but you only want to replace the *instance* that is caputred in the group?  Then you're out of luck, you'd replace all the others.  Eg: replace "Foo Bar Ba(a)z Quux" groups[1] with "" and you'd get "Foo Br Bz Quux"

Comment: @Pxtl This is an old answer, I do not remember what it is about. Your example [yields a different output](https://ideone.com/TcTqML), not sure what you expect and what exact code you are using.